# My coding indicate these error, how to solve?

Tags: java, android, andengine

Hi now i am try to implement ndk project keyboard and trackball class into andengine but now andengine indicate these error, how to solve these error please help me?

```
Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK cannot be resolved    AbstractMultitouchPad.java    /keytrack
/src/com/momojo/gba/input    line 74    Java Problem
MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK cannot be resolved    GameScreen.java    /keytrack/src/com
/momojo/gba    line 92    Java Problem
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN cannot be resolved    AbstractMultitouchPad.java    
/keytrack/src/com/momojo/gba/input    line 78    Java Problem
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN cannot be resolved    AbstractMultitouchPad.java    
/keytrack/src/com/momojo/gba/input    line 90    Java Problem
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN cannot be resolved    GameScreen.java    /keytrack
/src/com/momojo/gba    line 97    Java Problem
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT cannot be resolved    
AbstractMultitouchPad.java    /keytrack/src/com/momojo/gba/input    line 82    Java   
Problem
```

Comment: `MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK` etc. -> Is MotionEvent imported and on the class path?

Comment: yes i import these class path in my coding import android.view.MotionEvent;

Comment: I'm no Android expert, but if you have the class on the classpath as well (MotionEvent looks like a standard ui class) there might be a version problem. Can you check which version you are using for development and which version is provided by the system or included in the app?

Comment: build target 1.6 and version 4

Comment: Which versions are you using for dev and which one at runtime?
As I said, I'm no Android expert, I just want to giva a hint what might be the problem. `cannot be resolved` sounds like either the class `MotionEvent` cannot be found or you have a version in which `MotionEvent` doesn't have `ACTION_MASK` etc. yet.

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem. It's because android API level is too low. I raised android API level to 2.1 in the project property, then the errors gone. Just some clue.I didn't try to find the exact difference between API versions.